# Downgrade .NET version and Prism to run on XP

Tags: .net, wpf, wix

I have created a WIX custom bootstrapper for my msi bundle. 
I used MVVM pattern. and used Prism 5.0.0

and the .NET framework was 4.5

Now i have to use it on XP. and support this installer to .NET framework 3.5 (It is working if i use .NET 4.0)
How can i change the .NET framework and what version of Prism should i use with it. 
If not prism, is there any package compatible with .NET 3.5 ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recompile your .NET application against .NET Framework 3.5. Change target framework under Project->Properties->Application in Visual Studio and rebuild the application.

You also need to use [Prism 2.2](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/46046). No newer version is compatible with .NET Framework 3.5.

Of course you won't be able to use any features (and fixes!) that were introduced in .NET Framework 4+ and Prism4+, so you might have to rewrite your application quite a lot depending on how many "new" features you are actually using.

It should be noted that neither XP nor .NET Framework 3.5 is officially supported by Microsoft any longer.

Comment: And you'll be also missing 10 years of bugfixing in .NET. This is an argument managers may understand (assuming you won't do such a downgrade for fun).